# what the datatype of multivalue : list of string in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-relationship, class-diagram

I want to know what the datatype of a list of strings in SQL?
how can I store a list of String in my database?

I am working in application and there is a checkbox to choose hobbies, more than one, so how can I store that?

pleas help me with this.

Comment: save each in his own row and if they are linked give them the same id in a second column. and read this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: A) Use a one-to-many structure as defined by [database normalization rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). B) Use a JSON column. Don't use B if this data is in any way involved in other relations, as in you need to search it or index it.

Comment: List of strings is not advised. Better store them in normalised form, because string parsing is an expensive operation

Answer (score 1):

This is what you have to do if I understand what you asking.
This is the conceptual model.

[image: ERD]

- One user can have none or many Hobby
- One hobby is choose by none or many users

You have the following table :

```
User(id,name)
Hobby(id, code, label)
User_Hobby(id_user, id_hobbies)
--> id_user is foreign key of User(id)
--> id_hobbies is foreign key of Hobbies(id)
```

(I'm sorry i'm struggling on how to write hobby... Because i'm french and don't know how you write this word at singular... oh my god my poor english, so let's assume that hobbies to singular is "Hobby")